# How to on efficient and quick way add prefix to number and remove?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, stl

How to on efficient and quick way add prefix to number and remove ? (number can have arbitrary number of digits, number doesn't have limit)
I have number for example 122121 and I want to add digit 9 at the begining to be 9122121, after that I need to remove first digit in number. I have split into vector, push front digit(in this case 9) and the create number from digits ( iteration with multiplying 10).
Is there more efficient way ?

Comment: `int x = 122121; x += 9000000;` - You'll have to be more specific about what your problem is.

Comment: Take a look at the rather verbose but efficient binary search below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want efficiency, don't use anything else than numbers, no vectors, strings, etc. In your case:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long add_prefix( unsigned long long number, unsigned prefix )
{
    // if you want the example marked (X) below to print "9", add this line:
    if( number == 0 ) return prefix;

    // without the above, the result of (X) would be "90"

    unsigned long long tmp = ( number >= 100000 ) ? 1000000 : 10;
    while( number >= tmp ) tmp *= 10;
    return number + prefix * tmp;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << add_prefix( 122121, 9 ) << std::endl; // prints 9122121
    std::cout << add_prefix( 122121, 987 ) << std::endl; // prints 987122121
    std::cout << add_prefix( 1, 9 ) << std::endl; // prints 91
    std::cout << add_prefix( 0, 9 ) << std::endl; // (X) prints 9 or 90
}
```

but watch out for overflows. Without overflows, the above even works for multi-digit prefixes. I hope you can figure out the reverse algorithm to remove the prefix.

---

**Edited:** As Andy Prowl pointed out, one could interpret 0 as "no digits", so the prefix should *not* be followed by the digit 0. But I guess it depends on the OPs use-case, so I edited the code accordingly.

Comment: @W.B.: This question is about efficiency, you'll need a benchmark to convince me of your version.

Comment: Efficiency in terms of performance or in terms of code simplicity ;)? I'll let the OP do the benchmarking :)

Comment: @DanielFrey: I think if `number` has just 1 digit this won't work. You may want to [slightly modify it](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx$12)

Comment: Couldn't resist, it's roughly equivalent, your version (100 million iterations) run 9.5 seconds, mine run 9.8 secs.

Comment: for pure efficiency, replace the division with just comparison to 10, 100, 1000....

Comment: @W.B.: Please benchmark again with the edited version, I got rid of the division :) Please remove the first line if (X) yields 90 in your case for a fair comparison.

Comment: @Daniel Frey, your second version is almost twice as fast, ie 5.2 seconds. After fixing my version (see comments below my answer), it run for 17 seconds, so in terms of performance, yours is much more efficient.

Comment: @W.B.: Thank you for benchmarking it! For this, +1 for your answer.

Comment: @Alexander: Thanks, but for my version, you need to take out `if(number==0)return prefix;` to make it compatible and hence comparable with the other versions.

Comment: @Alexander: I borrowed one trick from yours, should be a bit faster now :) See the edited version above.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate number of digits using floor(log10(number)) + 1. So the code would look like:

```
int number = 122121;
int noDigits = floor(log10(number)) + 1;
//Add 9 in front
number += 9*pow(10,noDigits);
//Now strip the 9
number %= pow(10,noDigits);
```

I hope I got everything right ;)

Comment: Yes, it's late, I get it now. ^ is XOR. I needed power of, my bad

Answer (score 2):

I shall provide an answer that makes use of binary search and a small benchmark of the answers provided so far.

### Binary Search

The following function uses binary search to find the number of digits of the desired number and appends the desired digit in front of it.

```
int addPrefix(int N, int digit) {
    int multiplier = 0;
    // [1, 5]
    if(N <= 100000) {
        // [1, 3]
        if(N <= 1000) {
            //[1, 2]
            if(N <= 100) {
                //[1, 1]
                if(N <= 10) {
                    multiplier = 10;
                //[2, 2]
                } else {
                    multiplier = 100;
                }
            //[3, 3]
            } else {
                multiplier = 1000;
            }
        //[4, 4]
        } else if(N <= 10000) {
            multiplier = 10000;
        //[5, 5]
        } else {
            multiplier = 100000;
        }
    //[6, 7]
    } else if(N <= 10000000) {
        //[6, 6]
        if(N <= 1000000) {
            multiplier = 1000000;
        //[7, 7]
        } else {
            multiplier = 10000000;
        }
    //[8, 9]
    } else {
        //[8, 8]
        if(N <= 100000000) {
            multiplier = 100000000;
        //[9, 9]
        } else {
            multiplier = 1000000000;
        }
    }
    return N + digit * multiplier;
}
```

It is rather verbose. But, it finds the number of digits for a number in the range of `int` in a maximum of 4 comparisons.

### Benchmark

I created a small benchmark running each provided algorithm against 450 million iterations, 50 million iterations per number of determined number of digits.

```
int main(void) {
    int i, j, N = 2, k;
    for(i = 1; i < 9; ++i, N *= 10) {
        for(j = 1; j < 50000000; ++j) {
            k = addPrefix(N, 9);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The results:

```
+-----+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| run | Alexander | Daniel Frey | kkuryllo | W.B.    |
+-----+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 1st |    2.204s |      3.983s |   5.145s | 23.216s |
+-----+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 2nd |    2.189s |      4.044s |   5.081s | 23.484s |
+-----+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| 3rd |    2.197s |      4.232s |   5.043s | 23.378s |
+-----+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
| AVG |    2.197s |      4.086s |   5.090s | 23.359s |
+-----+-----------+-------------+----------+---------+
```

[You can find the sources used in this Gist here](https://gist.github.com/aeurielesn/6cff01aac21367d6520c).

Comment: +1 for the idea and comparison. Manual binary search is a bit verbose though.

Comment: It's  different from my results a bit.  Are you sure you excluded the stripping part from my code,  not that it should matter for the verdict though?

Comment: @W.B., You can check the sources yourself at the bottom there's a link to a Gist. In short, yes, I'm sure

Comment: Fair enough, maybe it's a matter of compiler specific implementation of math algorithms (log10, pow, floor)...

Answer (score 1):

How about using lexical cast from boost? That way you're not doing the iteration and all the yourself.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html

Answer (score 1):

%First find the highest power of 10 greater than your number.  Then multiple the addition by that and add to your number

For example:

```
int x;
int addition;
int y = 1;
while (y <= x)
{
    y *= 10;
}

x += addition * y;
```

I didn't test this code so just take as an example...
I also don't really understand your other instructions, you'll need to clarify.

edit okay I think I understand that you also want to remove the first digit sometime as well.  You can use a simular approach to do this.

```
int x;
int y = 1;
while (y <= x*10)
{
    y *= 10;
}

x %= y;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could put the digits in an std::string and use insert and delete but it might be an overkill